# Using PRIMARY clipboard in macOS

Tags: macos, unix, copy-paste, x11

I use Linux (CentOS) at work and quite like the PRIMARY clipboard. This adds highlighted text to a clipboard automatically and pastes the contents of that clipboard on center-button mouse click. Importantly, this clipboard does not overwrite the CLIPBOARD clipboard.

I would love to get this functionality on my macOS home machine. I have tried [MacPaste](https://github.com/rsmz/macpaste), but this overwrites the CLIPBOARD clipboard. Does there exist any utility (graphical or command-line, free or paid) that unlocks this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

According to OSX Daily, there is an alternative clipboard with the Mac that will not overwrite the standard clipboard. The commands are Control-k, which does a cut on selected text (not copy) and Control-y which then pastes that data. The article is here: http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/01/use-a-secondary-cut-and-paste-function-to-avoid-overwriting-clipboard-contents/

The article also mentions a 3rd part app, ClipMenu which also might address your desires.